# Using different analyzers for different fields in same query in arangosearch views

Tags: arangodb

I have a use case where given a user input I want to search across different fields. So I am able to do a query like

```
for v in myview
    search analyzer(v.host_name == tokens(SOME_INPUT, 'text_en')[0] OR 
                    v.ip_address == tokens(%input%, 'text_en')[0], "text_en")
    return v
```

and it works.

But now some of the fields have different analyzer so I in the above query, I would like to use e.g. ngram for ip_address but then the above query will not work as the second argument to analyzer(....) is *text_en*.

Reading the docs at https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-search.html, it does not seem like I can have multiple SEARCH stanza in the same query.

What would be the way to do a query like that?

Comment: I read this `if an Analyzer argument is passed to a nested function regardless, then it takes precedence over the Analyzer set via ANALYZER()` to mean that you are free to use different analyzers in nested search-functions - the one given to `analyzer()` itself allows you to omit it nested functions (so your two 'text_en' to `tokens()` are redundant).